# Upon button press, open up mail and have user send email to specified address?

Tags: swift, email, button, message

I was wondering if there is a relatively straightforward function that would allow a user in my app to press a button, have the mail app open, and let that user write a brief message to the already established (& greyed out) receiver of the email?

Answer (score 0):

```
let email = "foo@bar.com"
let url = NSURL(string: "mailto:\(email)")!
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
```